# Determining Fixed Effects and Random Effect

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have finished collecting data for my research.

The outcome is rat burrow activeness - (yes/no)

The predictor variables are gender, maturity, paddy stages, months, distance of burrow from house/river/bush/paddyfield/railroad, nearby burrow count, undergrowth area/depth and rice paddy boundary heights/width.

My advisor strongly recommend me to use generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs) for analysis.

I have spend few days learning about GLMMS and I'm stuck on determining which of my predictor variables are fixed effects and which are random effects.

Currently, my conclusion is
gender, maturity, paddy stages, months and distance form x/y/z, nearby burrow counts are fixed
and
undergrowth area/depth, and rice paddy boundary height/width are random.

However, I'm not 100% sure.

Please guide me or suggest me a solid reading. Thank you

Edit: Burrow is not owned by a specific rat, hence, the sex have three categories, male, female, and both.

Then same goes for maturity, where it can have Adult/Juvenile/Both

Based from the way data is recorded, does this means gender/maturity is a random effects?

Comment: None of the variables described seem like candidates for random intercepts. Do you have repeated measures or other clustering of the dependant variable? If so what is the grouping factor ?

Comment: Basically there are 80 burrow points, which i inspect once per paddy growth stage (5 stages in total).  Hence, totaling to 400 data collection for burrow activeness.   Therefore, the grouping factor might be paddy stages and the repeated measures is the inspection that i  have done?